# Viewing Videos without download on an Android project with firebase

Tags: android, firebase

I'm  newbie at Android. I'm trying to make a page look like an instagram page. When you see the video it starts to play then you can scroll over.

I'm trying to use firebase but you have to download video first. (I might wrong about that)

How can I make that happen?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use online video player libraries suitable as per your need.
just fetch the download url from `Firebase storage` of your item put that into video library player as video link and all will be done by library after that you can flush or delete the cache of your app to save memory in mobile [This library could be one protyposis MediaPlayer Extended](https://github.com/protyposis/MediaPlayer-Extended) read the documentation of this and it will help you...

Comment: Thanks for helping. I also find another library:
 (https://github.com/eneim/toro) if anyone looking for.

Comment: Very good..your work should done despite of which one you use...happy coding :)